# AWS - The CIDR is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have a VPC with the following IP 10.143.161.128/28. My solution will need probably 6 IP's. How should I defined the subsets so it will work in AWS.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason that your VPC is configured with /28 (that's just 16 IP addresses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use this CIDR because any subnet will be using 5 IP addresses for internal use so that leaves nothing for you

10.143.161.128/27 this will be enough for 6 IPs

Comment: VPC reserves 5 IP addresses, not 6. And a /28 has 16 IP addresses.

Comment: Hi jarmod, Can you please add a breakdown of a 6 available IP's for /28. Thanks